# Dynamic tables in Entity Framework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, dynamic-tables

The table has to be created dynamically. The table name is dynamic (is sent to API) and columns are static.
Every time api is called, a new table is been created with different name.

Is it possible to do that in Entity Framework? If so - how?
DB is Posstgress.
Thanks

ADO is not the accepted way. I need to do it with Entity Framework.
I tried to write migration that will be activated just when API is called. But it seems that migration can run only when running first.

Comment: I suspect there's a lot of confusion here. `ADO is not the accepted way. I need to do it with Entity Framework.` You're already using ADO.NET. EF is an ORM, not a data access library. It generates SQL queries that get executed by ADO.NET commands using ADO.NET connections. NpgSQL is an ADO.NET provider. EF deals with *objects*, not tables. Its job, like any ORM, is to map query results to objects and give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of in-memory tables.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a SQL generator for `CREATE TABLE`, not an ORM.  Migrations aren't EF's way of running `CREATE TABLE`. They're a way of modifying the database to match a changed *object* model. They're meant to run only when the application starts. When they run they *do* generate `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of tables with the same columns and you want to switch between them at runtime, you can use [SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries).

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql($"SELECT * FROM {QuoteName(tableName)}")
    .ToList();
```

where QuoteName prevents SQL Injection attacks. This one is for SQL Server:

```
private static string QuoteName(string identifier)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(identifier.Length + 3, 1024);
    sb.Append('[');
    foreach (var c in identifier)
    {
        if (c == ']')
            sb.Append(']');
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    sb.Append(']');
    return sb.ToString();
}
```